# jQuery promise:callback function called at once

Tags: jquery, promise, video.js

I use function `doPlaySequence` to play several videos and then show a picture with function `drawConfig`. I wrote the code like this:

```js
function wait(dtd) {
  var dtd = $.Deferred();
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    doPlaySequence();
    dtd.resolve();
  }, 0);
  
  return dtd.promise();
}

wait().then(drawConfig);
```

However `drawConfig` is called at once while the videos don't end. I just copied the example simply so the code may looks ugly. I use video.js to help to play video.

```js
var stropsrc = new Array(3);
stropsrc[0]= "../rs/MOVIE/KlogoPk.mp4";
stropsrc[1]="../rs/MOVIE/theme.mp4";
stropsrc[2]= "../rs/MOVIE/OpPk.mp4";

function doPlaySequence()
{
  var divcontainer = document.createElement("div");
  divcontainer.setAttribute("id","divop");
  document.body.appendChild(divcontainer);

  var playID = "op0";

  var opplay = document.createElement('video');
  opplay.setAttribute("id",playID);
  opplay.preload = "none";


  divcontainer.appendChild(opplay);

  opplay.src = stropsrc[0];


  var AttrObj = {"datacount":0};
  var myPlayer;
  videojs.setAttributes(opplay,AttrObj);


  myPlayer = videojs(opplay);
  myPlayer.play();


  opplay.addEventListener("ended",function(e)
  {
    e.preventDefault();

    var c = parseInt(this.getAttribute("datacount"))+1;
    if(c < 3)
    {
      opplay.src = stropsrc[c];
      AttrObj.datacount = c;
      videojs.setAttributes(opplay,AttrObj);

      myPlayer = videojs(opplay);
      myPlayer.play();

    }
    else//end
    {

      /*reset*/
      opplay.src = stropsrc[0];
      AttrObj.datacount = 0;
      videojs.setAttributes(opplay,AttrObj);


      /*hide*/
      var divContainer = document.getElementById("divop");

      divContainer.style.display = "none";
      divContainer.style.visibility = "hidden";

      var divOP = document.getElementById("op0");
      divOP.style.display = "none";
      divOP.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
  });
```

Comment: That's the expected behaviour - you have set the timeout to `0`, hence it executes immediately. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I want  that drawConfig  is called after doPlaySequence running out(the videos play to end) but it is called at once.

Comment: Could you please add the code of `doPlaySequence()` to your question.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That's ok,thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To only run the `drawConfig` function *after* the video completes you either need to call it from within the videos' `ended` event handler, or create a promise that resolves in that event. Try this:

```
function doPlaySequence()
{
  var deferred = $.Deferred();

  // your code...

  var opplay = document.createElement('video');
  // opplay logic here...

  opplay.addEventListener("ended", function(e) {
    // video ended logic here...

    deferred.resolve();
  }

  return deferred;
}

doPlaySequence().then(drawConfig);
```

You'll see that the `doPlaySequence` function now returns the deferred which is only resolved once the video has stopped playing. In turn, `drawConfig` will then be called.

Answer (score 1):

video.js player has an ended event to which you should listen to, and you should resolve your Deferer object post that.

In your doPlaySequence() do,

```
 myPlayer.on('ended', function() {
    dtd.resolve();
 });
```

You might need to pass your dtd object to doPlaySequence, or simply create it inside doPlaySequence, since it's only objective is to wait until the video has played completely.

Setting timeout will not serve your purpose.

Comment: Yeah,I got it.I should resolve it at the whole videos end,at the "else" branch.I learn the code executes  in sequence except  video and pic.

Comment: To make code concise, I must use closure instead of writing whole video code into wait function?